# Testing Exception in junit tests fails even after the exception is thrown

Tags: exception, junit, annotations, runtimeexception

Hello I am unit testing a method using the junit @Rule annotation ,

```
@Rule 
public ExpectedException exception  = ExpectedException.none(); 

@Test
public void testException() {
  //do something that throws RuntimeException
  exception.expect(RuntimeException.class);
}
```

The test fails with the Runtime exception when it should actually pass expecting the exception. Is there anything else I need to do
?

Comment: Your code shows `@test`, you really have `@Test`, right? Also, why not just try `@Test(expected=RuntimeException.class)`?

Answer (score 1):

`exception.expect(RunTimeException.class)` must be called before the code that throws the exception is executed.

```
@Rule 
public ExpectedException exception  = ExpectedException.none(); 

@Test
public void testException() {
  exception.expect(RunTimeException.class);
  //do something that throws RunTimeException
}
```

Comment: No, this didn't seem to fix the issue

Comment: what's the error message after making the change suggested in this answer

Comment: Same, it fails saying expected "RuntimeException" whereas I am getting the expected runtimeException

Comment: Could you please post the start of your test class. Something like `public class MyTest {`